# PHP Laravel Parents inherit dynamic static parameters from children

Tags: php, laravel, oop, inheritance

I am working with Laravel Eloquent models and have gotten stuck on an inheritence issue.

I have got `BaseModel` class, which has `protected static $dynamicRelations = [];` parameter, and some methods to work with that.

And then I have multiple other classes, extending `BaseModel`, for this example let's say `PageModel` and `EventModel`.

If I create a dynamic relation on the page model, as such `PageModel::setDynamicRelation`, it puts it in the static variable:

```
    public static function setDynamicRelation($key, $callback)
    {
        static::$dynamicRelations[$key] = $callback;
    }
```

This way, I can add a dynamic relationship to the model. So if I do `PageModel::setDynamicRelation('banners', ...)`, then on an instance of `PageModel` I can call `PageModel->banners` to retrieve the relationship values.

The issue is, that the relations are kept in the `BaseModel` static parameter, and are inherited by other models. So if I set the relationsip on `PageModel`, and then instantiate an `EventModel`, it also gets those same relationships, which is not correct.

How can I make it so that the relationships are stored in the child class and are not inherited by other classes? I.e. need to store a copy of `$dynamicRelations` on the class that the methods are called upon, so all the children don't share same relations?

Thanks!

Comment: if you want something that dynamic why not use morph?

Comment: @jycr753 could you expand on this please? I have a structure where I need to allow modules changing other modules, so a module called `PageBanners` can add a dynamic relationship to the `Page` model, without actually changing the code in `Page` model.

Comment: That shouldn't be happening.  In your example, `EventModel` shouldn't be  getting the relationships of the `PageModel`, they are two different instances.

Comment: Yes, that is my exact problem. They both extend same `BaseModel`, which has the static parameter, and they seem to share it for some reason?

Comment: To be clear, I add a relationship using a static method, so like `PageModel::setDynamicRelationship`, however instances of both `PageModel` and `EventModel` inherit the same relationships from the `BaseModel::$dynamicRelationships`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have tests showing this?

So you are stating that you do not want [Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/language.oop5.late-static-bindings)

Static properties on parent classes that are defined in child classes don't propagate to other child instances that extend the parent model.  For example, `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` has the `protected static $globalScopes = [];` property but when you add a global scope to any model extending `Model` it pushes it in this array just as you are doing with your `$dynamicRelationships` array but those instances do not get reflected in the classes extending `Model`.

[See Laravel's implementation of this here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L356)

Comment: I thought there would be a more elegant solution than keeping `static::class` as the array keys, but if the framework is doing that way then it must be good enough. Thanks a lot for this!